# let div fill complete height of parent div

Tags: html, css

I think I tried every solution posted here on stackoverflow except the correct solution for sure.
2 hours nothing then give a div an 100% height, very frustating.

Maybe I'm just tired (Night in Germany) and someone see the correct solution in seconds.

Everything looks great, except the div with the class "layout_content_middle" which have an repeatable background image.
The "id=content" div has the correct 100% height, but the conainer div inside the content div doesn't and this is the problem.

Here my current code.
Important note, this is an bootstrap project, so I work with container and grid classes.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent header and footer by its height */
  margin: -80px auto -165px;
  /* Pad bottom by header and footer height */
  padding: 80px 0 165px;
}
/* Set the fixed height of the header here */

#header {
  height: 80px;
}
/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */

#footer {
  height: 165px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 983px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="layout_content_top"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 983px; background-color: red; height: 100%">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="layout_content_middle">


          asdasd asd ad as das d as

          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 983px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 16px">
        <div class="layout_footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the !important rule set for `height: auto`, which overrides your `height: 100%`, making your height automatic which causes your to expand only as much as necessary to fit the content.

So the following rule needs to be removed:

```
#content {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

---

See it in action here:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent header and footer by its height */
  margin: -80px auto -165px;
  /* Pad bottom by header and footer height */
  padding: 80px 0 165px;
}
/* Set the fixed height of the header here */

#header {
  height: 80px;
}
/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */

#footer {
  height: 165px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 983px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="layout_content_top"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 983px; background-color: red; height: 100%">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="layout_content_middle">


          asdasd asd ad as das d as

          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />asd
          <br />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container" style="max-width: 983px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 16px">
        <div class="layout_footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Looked great at the beginning but only works as long as the content is not enough to need scrolling the page.

Comment: If I remove the height: 100% on the inside div the opposite is the case, looks bad if no scrolling is required but great if scrolling is required. I'm so frustrated!

Comment: Oh, it's because of the negative margins you're using.

Comment: No Solution available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: relative` on the parent, then add `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;` and left and right if you want to fill the width.

Comment: I put relativ on id=content and absolut on class=container inside.
Doesn't work because the content get pin to the left and not in the middle anymore and if there is more content then in my example to force scolling, the inside div is not "growing" with the page.